# pandas from date as string to format that I can shift in a loop with shift()

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a simple string :

```
startdate="2012-01-01"
```

I want to convert it somehow in a format that lets me shift it per day/month. I know there is a shift() command

I tried

```
start= pd.to_datetime(startdate)
```

but I cannot find a solution to shift it, just to extract the various components of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be down by convert to index

```
pd.to_datetime(pd.Index([startdate])).shift(1,freq='D')
Out[21]: DatetimeIndex(['2012-01-02'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```